# Why does function not count the number of asked characters in list?

Tags: python, function

Learning python. I want to make a tic-tac-toe game where two people take turns to choose coordinates where they want to place their sign. I defined all winning positions in a list named 'all_wins'. Then I declared a function named 'check_win' that should check if either 'X' or 'O' has won the game, but it doesn't work at all.

I tried placing the function calls in different spots of the while loop, but nothing actually happened, as if my function doesn't exist.

```
user_input = "         "  # 9 empty spaces, representing the empty grid


def board():
    print("---------")
    print("|", user_input[0], user_input[1], user_input[2], "|")
    print("|", user_input[3], user_input[4], user_input[5], "|")
    print("|", user_input[6], user_input[7], user_input[8], "|")
    print("---------")


all_wins = [[user_input[0:3]], [user_input[3:6]], [user_input[6:9]],
            [user_input[0:7:3]], [user_input[1:8:3]], [user_input[2:9:3]],
            [user_input[0:9:4]], [user_input[2:7:2]]]


def check_win(player):
    global loop_counter
    for j in all_wins:
        if j.count(player) == 3:
            print(player, "wins")
            loop_counter += 1


board()

turn_counter = 1
loop_counter = 0

while loop_counter < 1:

    user_step = input()
    try:
        new_step_list = [int(x) for x in user_step.split(" ")]
    except ValueError:
        print("You should enter numbers!")
        user_step = input()
        continue
    coor1 = new_step_list[0]
    coor2 = new_step_list[1]

    try:
        if 0 < coor1 and coor2 < 4:
            if user_input[(coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)] == " ":
                list_of_chars = list(user_input)
                if turn_counter % 2 == 1:
                    list_of_chars[(coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)] = "X"
                else:
                    list_of_chars[(coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)] = "O"
                user_input = "".join(list_of_chars)
                turn_counter += 1

            elif user_input[(coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)] == "X" or "O":
                print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
                continue
        else:
            print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
            continue
    except IndexError:
        print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
        continue

    check_win("X")
    check_win("O")
    if list(user_input).count(" ") == 0:
        print("Draw")
        loop_counter += 1

    board()
```

Comment: Never say that "it doesn't work at all": [say _what it does_](/help/how-to-ask) and then explain what you expected it to do instead (as well as what you already did in terms of (re)searching and debugging so that folks don't ask you to try things you already tried)

Comment: `all_wins` is defined based on the initial contents of `user_input`, which is all spaces.  Changing `user_input` later on does not affect `all_wins`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all_wins` variable is not in right place, here is the updated code that works:

```py
def board():
    print("---------")
    print("|", user_input[0], user_input[1], user_input[2], "|")
    print("|", user_input[3], user_input[4], user_input[5], "|")
    print("|", user_input[6], user_input[7], user_input[8], "|")
    print("---------")

def check_win(player):
    all_wins = [
        user_input[0:3], user_input[3:6], user_input[6:9],  # rows
        user_input[0:7:3], user_input[1:8:3], user_input[2:9:3],  # columns
        user_input[0:9:4], user_input[2:7:2]  # diagonals
    ]
    for j in all_wins:
        if j.count(player) == 3:
            print(player, "wins")
            return True
    return False

user_input = " " * 9  # 9 empty spaces, representing the empty grid
board()

turn_counter = 1

while True:
    user_step = input("Enter the coordinates: ")
    try:
        new_step_list = [int(x) for x in user_step.split(" ")]
        coor1 = new_step_list[0]
        coor2 = new_step_list[1]
        if not 1 <= coor1 <= 3 or not 1 <= coor2 <= 3:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("You should enter valid coordinates (1 to 3) separated by a space!")
        continue

    index = (coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)
    if user_input[index] != " ":
        print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
        continue

    user_input = user_input[:index] + ("X" if turn_counter % 2 == 1 else "O") + user_input[index + 1:]
    turn_counter += 1

    if check_win("X"):
        break
    if check_win("O"):
        break
    if " " not in user_input:
        print("Draw")
        break

    board()
```

Other approach:

```py
def board():
    print("---------")
    print("|", user_input[0], user_input[1], user_input[2], "|")
    print("|", user_input[3], user_input[4], user_input[5], "|")
    print("|", user_input[6], user_input[7], user_input[8], "|")
    print("---------")

def check_win(player):
    all_wins = [[user_input[0], user_input[1], user_input[2]], [user_input[3], user_input[4], user_input[5]],
                [user_input[6], user_input[7], user_input[8]], [user_input[0], user_input[3], user_input[6]],
                [user_input[1], user_input[4], user_input[7]], [user_input[2], user_input[5], user_input[8]],
                [user_input[0], user_input[4], user_input[8]], [user_input[2], user_input[4], user_input[6]]]

    for j in all_wins:
        if j.count(player) == 3:
            print(player, "wins")
            return True

    return False

user_input = "         "  # 9 empty spaces, representing the empty grid

board()

turn_counter = 1
loop_counter = 0

while loop_counter < 1:
    user_step = input()
    try:
        new_step_list = [int(x) for x in user_step.split(" ")]
    except ValueError:
        print("You should enter numbers!")
        user_step = input()
        continue

    coor1 = new_step_list[0]
    coor2 = new_step_list[1]

    try:
        if 0 < coor1 and coor2 < 4:
            if user_input[(coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)] == " ":
                list_of_chars = list(user_input)
                if turn_counter % 2 == 1:
                    list_of_chars[(coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)] = "X"
                else:
                    list_of_chars[(coor1 - 1) * 3 + (coor2 - 1)] = "O"
                user_input = "".join(list_of_chars)
                turn_counter += 1
            else:
                print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
                continue
        else:
            print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
            continue
    except IndexError:
        print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
        continue

    if check_win("X"):
        loop_counter += 1
    elif check_win("O"):
        loop_counter += 1
    elif list(user_input).count(" ") == 0:
        print("Draw")
        loop_counter += 1

    board()
```